# laravel - 500 error when I updated a file on server, how is it possible?

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-500

I really don't understand how it can be possible... The site angelescielo.com/candidatas was working... But I have this PHP (candidatas.blade.php... And as far as I understand the blade extension is from Laravel) ...

I updated its DOM (not even PHP code) to remove a text. But now it doesn't work anymore ... (I get a WSOD and debugging the only thing I see is a 500 error) And the only modification was to a span tag .

I've been trying to see the logs according to other posts I've seen around Internet and StackOverflow but I can't see the reason of the 500 error, I'm desperate and now I don't know where to start from.

Comment: Look in `storage\logs\laravel.log` for errors

Comment: The 300Mb log had the file path with permission denied... It was a framework file, changing permissions to that file solved the problem... Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is very often comes when you upload first time your website on server. In such cases changing permissions for folders helps.

Try to use this commands in terminal

```
sudo chmod 755 -R laravel_site
chmod -R o+w laravel_site/storage
```

laravel_site - is the laravel folder